# Clear the contents of a file using low level functions

Tags: c, file, low-level

***I would like to write a function able to delete contents of files.***

I have some thoughts of how to do it and here is the program that come up from them:

```
/*fclr - clear file contents*/
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int fd;

    if(--argc == 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Incorrect syntax. Usage: cat <filename1> <filname2> ... <filenameN>.\n");
    while(--argc > 0){
        char c = EOF;
        if((fd = open(*++argv, O_WRONLY, 0)) == -1)
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open the file.\n");
        lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET); //lseek here is redundant.
        write(fd, &c, sizeof(char));
        close(fd);
    }
}
```

Basically, I suppused, if a file is seen a very big array of characters, is has to have and end in memory. So as well as \0 works for stings, I thought EOF will do for actual files, but is not working. After the file is ran, the content is still there.

Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem.

*(I do know that opening a file with fopen on "w" mode will delete the whole content, but I would like to achieve the same result with low level functions)*

Comment: If you want an empty file, you shouldn't write any bytes into it.  There's a POSIX system call for this, `truncate(2)` which avoids even having to open the file, letting you set its length to 0.  Or open it with `O_TRUNC` like a shell redirect would, or if already open, use `ftruncate`.

Comment: Also, seems like you haven't understood the difference between C strings (implicit terminated, indicated by a `0` byte) vs. explicit-length buffers like an array + length.  Files have a length stored separately from the data, so `ls -l` can tell you the file length without having to open+read every file searching for a `0` bytes (instead using the `stat` system call; try `strace ls -l` to see the syscalls it makes).  And so files can contain multiple zeros, just like an array of `char` or `int` can! Arbitrary binary data pretty much needs to be explicit-length; that's why `write()` takes a len

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you only try to open as following? It truncates the file as you expect.

```
open(*++argv, O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY);
```